# TreeMap what wrong with "ё"?

Tags: java, treemap

task: try to calculate amount of letters in words from console;

problem: with letter "ё";

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String abc = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"; //alphabet
    //String abc = "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"; // without "ё";
    //String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";// eng

    char[] abcArray = abc.toCharArray();

    ArrayList<Character> alphabet = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < abcArray.length; i++)
    {
        alphabet.add(abcArray[i]);
    }

    //read console
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        String s = reader.readLine();
        if (s.isEmpty()) break;
        list.add(s.toLowerCase());
    }

    Map<Character, Integer> result = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();

    for (Character x : alphabet){
        int count = 0;
        for (String y : list){
            char[] data = y.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (x.equals(data[i])){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            result.put(x,count);
        }
    }
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> p : result.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(p.getKey() + " " + p.getValue());
    }
}
```

output code

```
    абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя
а 1
б 1
в 1
г 1
д 1
е 1
ж 1
з 1
и 1
й 1
к 1
л 1
м 1
н 1
о 1
п 1
р 1
с 1
т 1
у 1
ф 1
х 1
ц 1
ч 1
ш 1
щ 1
ъ 1
ы 1
ь 1
э 1
ю 1
я 1
ё 1
```

letter "ё" on bottom of list, but it should be between "e" and "ж"

[in debug mode - in cycle letter "ё" came after "e" and put in map after "e". But when we work with next one letter "ж" letter "ё" move to the bottom of list, and "ж" placed after "e".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCxqj.png)

If use alphabet without "ё" or english alphabet - all letters keep their position. 
My question is: why it happened? I do something wrong? I necessarily should used map.

Comment: Please include required information in the question itself, not as links to screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

By default, characters are sorted by their unicode value. You need to provide custom `Comparator` to have `TreeMap` sorted differently. Simplest way is to use 1-character long strings as the key and use `Collator`:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new TreeMap<>(Collator.getInstance(new Locale("ru")));
....
result.put(String.valueOf(x), count);
```

However, for performance reasons, I would avoid using `TreeMap` altogether and use simple `int[]` for counts, whose indices will match to that of `abcArray`. This way, you will avoid boxing and unboxing of Integers and Characters.